Problem when merge two probability distribution [Pointer Network]
I'm trying to re-implement Pointer Gen Net from this paper. Ya but you don't really need to read the paper.
To sum up briefly,
I have a vector probability distribution over vocabulary called p_vocab. This p_vocab is formed by softmax function
And another vector probability distribution over source sentence called p_src. This p_src also is formed by softmax function
Then I'll combined p_vocab and p_src by addition operator
p_final = p_vocab + p_src (each element >=0  because both used softmax function)
Okay, then in the paper they wrote:
loss = - log(P(w))

I agree that the model will try to increase the prob of target token and reduce the prob of other token in vocab via the procedure reduce loss so we multiply with minus one. Because the prob very small due to large vocab then the log make it more significant in loss.
But I get confuse now. Is it just a way to express that they're using cross entropy loss? As the formula of cross entropy loss is : -log(exp(P)/sum..)
I tried not to apply log in the p_final and pass the p_final in cross_entropy_loss. It works though loss reduce very lightly. Normally I use log_softmax instead of softmax but I have two probs vector here, then I tried to apply log function to p_final but I got nan in the loss, I guess because there are some zero in the p_final then I add a really small epsilon like 1e-10 to p_final to avoid zero case before calculate log
so
p_final = torch.log(p_final + 1e-10)

loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy_loss(p_final, labels)

Is my way correct?

Adding two probabilitiy distributions does not give you a probability distribution!! It will not sum up to 1. Have a look at crossValidated.SE for more info on cross entropy.
